# Longest valid subsequence

Tags: string, algorithm

I am encountering this coding problem.

> Given a string s, and a function isValid(String str), write a function
>   to check the longest subsequence in s that is valid. For example, a
>   subsequence in "whreat" can be "rat", "eat", "what" or "wheat". Please
>   don't speculate the implementation of isValid(String str) function.

At first, I thought I could use DP to solve the problem, but since we cannot assume anything about isValid(String str), i.e., "wh" is true doesn't indicate anything that "whe" will be true, so I don't think DP works here. The only solution I can think of is backtracking: get all subsequence of string and check each string. However, I don't think this is the optimal solution.

My question is, is there a better solution for this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dora, is reordering allowed? Is "tea" a good solution too?

Comment: @JeanLeMoignan No, subsequence must remain the initial order.

Comment: Without any additional restrictions, there is no way to do better than to check them all. Idea of a proof: Let's assume that only one subsequence is valid(among all subsequences). We will need to try them all to figure out which one exactly in the worst case.

Comment: You don't have to check every possible sub string. If you get a valid string of length 4 you know you don't need to check strings of length 3 or less. As a result of this fact you can start with the long combinations and work you way towards the smallest and halt when you find your first valid substring.

Comment: This works great as a recursive algorithm where you check `if isValid(s) return s; else return thisFunc(s+1,strlen(s)-1) || thisFunc(s,strlen(s)-1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optimize it by starting with the longest subsequences and if a valid subsequence of the long length was not found check the subsequences with less letters.

For example, you first check if choosing all the letters is a valid subSequence. If not then you'll test to see if there's a subsequence of length n-1 which isValid, etc. At each stage, if you got isValid=true you can simply return the subsequence found as it is promised to be the longest valid subsequence (as the longer subsequences were already disqualified).

For finding all the possible subsequences of length m < n you can use backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check every possible sub string. If you get a valid string of length 4 you know you don't need to check strings of length 3 or less. As a result of this fact you can start with the long combinations and work you way towards the smallest and halt when you find your first valid substring.

Comment: It does not change anything in the worst case(what if the longest valid subsequence has only one character?).

Comment: True, and the above algorithm is superior to checking all possible strings in every case that there is at least one valid substring of length greater than 0.

Comment: Even in the case where the longest valid substring only has one char you would halt when you find that string and potentially not check the other single character substrings.